# enchant.errors.Error: Don't pass bytestrings to pyenchant-python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a program where I can enter some characters in python and the program then goes through all the possible combinations of those letters. Then it compares that to check if it is in the dictionary or is a word. If it is, it gets appended to a list that will be printed out at the end. I had to look up how to do certain things and was doing great until I got this error. I can't find any forum that has this message. Can someone help me and tell me what I need to do to get it to work? Here is my code.

```
import itertools
import enchant
how_many_letters=True
letters=[]
possible_words=[]
d = enchant.Dict("en_US")
print("Welcome to combination letters helper!")
print("Type the word 'stop' to quit entering letters, other wise do it one at a time.")
while how_many_letters==True:
    get_letters=input("Enter the letters you have with not counting spaces:")
    if get_letters=='stop':
        how_many_letters=False
    letters.append(get_letters)
length=len(letters)
length=length-1
del letters[length:]
print(letters)
for i in range(length):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(letters, i):#Subset is the combination thing
    print(subset)
    check=d.check(subset)
    print(check)
    if check==True:
        possible_words.append(check)
print(possible_words)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to you question is this:

```
for i in range(1, length + 1):
  for subset in itertools.combinations(letters, i):#Subset is the combination thing
    s = ''.join(subset)
    print(s)
    check=d.check(s)
    print(check)
    if check==True:
        possible_words.append(s)
print(possible_words)
```

You need to pass enchant a string not a tuple and your range was not working.

(It's possible you may want to look at itertools.permutations(), I don't know if that is what you want though.)

Comment: The reason why I needed the length subtract one was to remove the 'stop' as that was just telling the loop to quit. But it looks like it does that with your code also. So I think I can remove it. Thanks for responding by the way. One thing is that the dictionary check isn't working as it is giving me combinations that isn't a word. I thought I did that correctly according to anther forum I looked at. What is wrong?

Comment: I just edited it as I saw you were using it to delete the stop word which I overlooked earlier. Can you give me examples of words is it saying are in the dictionary?

Comment: I tested it for the application I am using it for and it did not include all of the  words. Not good. Yet it is going through them all. So that is another problem. Anyways, for the words in the dictionary, here is an example.

Comment: I tested it for the application I am using it for and it did not include all of the  words. Not good. Yet it is going through them all. So that is another problem. Anyways, for the words in the dictionary, here is an example.Lets say the user enters: a,r,t,y,e,t,f,g,y. It has the word yet for example but it also prints like rt which isn't a word. It also doesn't say the word rat, which is possible. So problems here. Sorry, about the two comments, it won't let me post after editing.

Comment: itertools.permutations() will give you "rat" but it will take much longer to run. As for rt maybe it is an abbreviation of real time. I'm afraid you will have to live with false positives.

Comment: Ok, that worked. I think I have a way around the false positives thing. The user does know how many letters are in the word, just not what the word is. So I will have the user enter what that letter is and if the permutation length is = to the input, then add it to the list. Thanks for all your help.